# <i> tag in HAML

Tags: html, css, haml

How do I create a I-tag in haml?
Example:

```html
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAML` equivalent is

```
%i{class:"fa fa-search"}
```

You can look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNwbEP and see the compiled view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `.` shortcut:

```
%i.fa.fa-search
```

or the HTML-ish attribute variant

```
%i(class='fa fa-search')
```

I prefer the dot syntax.